# iOS Push Notification using Google FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, progressive-web-apps

With the new iOS 16.4 we are able to send notifications to web apps using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

When reading the docs on best practices we can see that refreshing the client token more than once weekly is not necessary:

> Whatever timing pattern you follow, make sure to update tokens periodically. An update frequency of once per month likely strikes a good balance between battery impact vs. detecting inactive registration tokens. By doing this refresh, you also ensure that any device which goes inactive will refresh its registration when it becomes active again. There is no benefit to doing the refresh more frequently than weekly.

As I understand it, we should only check the token freshness once a week and not every time the user opens the web app. Checking the token freshness is in my understanding only possible by calling

```
messaging.getToken()
```

So now I am using cookies to see if the user has opened the app within the last week and if the freshness cookie has expired, the app will call

```
messaging.getToken()
```

Sometimes however, on iPhone, the actual token expires while the user still has the freshness cookie on their device (because the 7 days are not over) and FCM can't push the notification to the user.

**So my question is: is there any disadvantage to call
messaging.getToken()
every time the user opens the web app** and compare it to the token stored on the server?
Is there another way of checking the freshness and comparing the tokens?

Firebase blog on FCM:

> There are scenarios when the existing token is changed:
> The app is restored on a new device
> The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> The user clears app data
> Certain device hardware failures can result in new tokens being created as a mechanism to work around the failures
> FCM may also force tokens to change by calling this method as part of their operations. An example of this is: if the token encryption
> key is compromised, FCM rolls out new tokens to all app instances.